# How can I prove that $\Gamma_{kij}+\Gamma_{kji}=\partial_k g_{ij}$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I want a simple proof of this identity:
 $$\Gamma_{kij}+\Gamma_{kji}=\partial_k g_{ij}$$ 
If there's no answer, give me a hint or something would help to prove it, and thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about the + sign between gammas? I feel it must be a minus.

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's + not -

Comment: The identity is not true; since the Christoffel symbols are symmetric in the last two indices, $\Gamma_{kij}+\Gamma_{kji}$ is just $2 \Gamma_{kij}$. Where did you get it from?

Comment: I think this should read: $\partial_k g_{ij} = \Gamma_{ikj}+\Gamma_{jki}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a proof:

Let $\varepsilon_n$ be a pre-euclidean space(Espace ponctuel)  and $ds^2$ a linear element :

$$ds^2=g_{ij}dx^idx^j$$
$n^3$ Christoffel symbols are $n(n+1)/2$ quantities. 
The definition of $g_{ij}$ is given by:
$$g_{ij}=\mathtt{e_i.e_j}$$
By differentiation :
$$dg_{ij}=\mathtt{e_i.}d\mathtt{e_j+e_j.}d\mathtt{e_i}$$
The expression of $d\mathtt{e_j}=w_j^l\mathtt{e_l}$ gives us the following:
$$dg_{ij}=(\mathtt{e_i.e_l})w_j^l+ (\mathtt{e_j.e_l})w_i^l=g_{il}w_j^l+g_{jl}w_i^l$$
The expression $g_{il}w_j^l$ represents the covariant transformation $w_j^l$ of the $d\mathtt{e_j}$ vector, The contravariant transform we'll need Christoffel Symbols:
$$w_{ij}=g_{il}w_j^l=g_{il}\Gamma_{kj}^ldu^k$$
We substitute this identity in the following relation:
$$\Gamma_{kji}=g_{jl}\Gamma_{ki}^l$$
and we get :
$$w_{ij}=\Gamma_{kij}du^k$$ 
The differentiation of $dg_{ij}$ given in the third formula can be written now like:
$$dg_{ij}=w_{ij}+w{ji}=(\Gamma_{kij}+\Gamma_{kji})du^k$$
Or it can be written :
 $$dg_{ij}=(\partial_kg_{ij})du^k$$
Pss: I'm not sure, I've found it in my notes and I used it here !!$$ $$
**Finally we get**

$$\Gamma_{kij}+\Gamma_{kji}=\partial_kg_{ij}$$

Comment: This seems wrong. I mean $\Gamma_{kij}$ is symmetric in lower indices, so addition of them should be just 2$\Gamma_{kij}$.

Comment: No, No, I'm actually using this property in Tensor calculus $\Gamma_{kij}+\Gamma_{kji}=\partial_kg_{ij}$ is a true identity and I'm sure about it !!